# Parsing Json in python 3, get email from API

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, parsing

I'm trying to do a little code that gets the emails (and other things in the future) from an API. But I'm getting "**TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str**" and I don't know what to do about it. I've been looking at other questions here but I still don't get it. I might be a bit slow when it comes to this.
I've also been watching some tutorials on the tube, and done the same as them, but still getting different errors. I run Python 3.5.

Here is my code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json, re
# Opens the url for the API
url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments'
r = urlopen(url)
# This should put the response from API in a Dict
result= r.read().decode('utf-8')
data = json.loads(result)

#This shuld get all the names from the the Dict
for name in data['name']: #TypeError here.
    print(name)
```

I know that I could regex the text and get the result that I want.
Code for that:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import re
url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments'
r = urlopen(url)
result = r.read().decode('utf-8')
f = re.findall('"email": "(\w+\S\w+)', result)
print(f)
```

But that seems like the wrong way to do this.
Can someone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you debug the type of `data` after you have parsed the JSON? It's almost certainly a list in which case you should loop over the list and then extract the email from whatever each element of the list is (probably a dict?)

Comment: `for object in data:
    print(object['name'])`

try this

Comment: @IainShelvington I get `<class 'list'>` when printing out the typ of `data`. So list was right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@PiAreSquared's comment is correct, just a bit more explanation here:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json, re
# Opens the url for the API
url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments'
r = urlopen(url)
# This should put the response from API in a Dict
result= r.read().decode('utf-8')
data = json.loads(result) 

# your data is a list of elements
# and each element is a dict object, so you can loop over the data
# to get the dict element, and then access the keys and values as you wish
# see below for some example
for element in data: #TypeError here.
  name = element['name']
  email = element['email']

# if you want to get all names, you should do
names = [element['name'] for element in data]
# same to get all emails
emails = [email['email'] for email in data]
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you. That made sense for me.

Answer (score 2):

`data` is a list of dicts, that's why you are getting `TypeError` while iterating on it.
The way to go is something like this:

```
for item in data:  # item is {"name": "foo", "email": "foo@mail..."}
    print(item['name'])
    print(item['email'])
```

Comment: Thank you! Would you say that this is more of a correct way to do it then using regex?

Comment: @Baconflip Definitely! As item is dictionary (hash-map), you can access values by key. No regex needed. In fact, that's (using regex) would be counterintuitive approach.